# Can't display inner associations when converting to JSON: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I render the object to JSON below it works fine:

```
class Api::ShopsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    shop = Shop.includes(:locations).find(params[:id])

    render json: shop.to_json(include: :locations)
  end
end
```

If I try and render an association inside of locations, I get an error:

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

This is what I am trying to do:

```
class Api::ShopsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    shop = Shop.includes(:locations).find(params[:id])
    render json: shop.to_json(include: [locations: [:categories]])

  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

My models are:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: shops
#
#  id         :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  name       :string           not null
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations
end


# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: locations
#
#  id         :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  shop_id    :integer          not null
#  name       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  has_many :categories
end


# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categories
#
#  id          :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  shop_id     :integer          not null
#  location_id :integer          not null
#  name        :string           not null
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :category_products
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: category_products
#
#  id          :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  category_id :integer          not null
#  product_id  :integer          not null
#  sort_order  :integer          not null
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class CategoryProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: Can you call `to_i` on params[:id]? I'm sure it is, just want to make sure.

Comment: @m.a.solano93 yes I can, yeah that's not the issue because like I said it works in the 1st case.

Comment: Ah, you wanted nested includes. Ok, do you have a categories endpoint? Does that be serialize just be fine?

Comment: I just have this endpoint right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [`to_json`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)docs, to include 2nd level and higher order associations, you should do like below

```
render json: shop.to_json(include: {locations: { include: {:categories}}})
```

**Update:**

The above code snippet is not working however, so I came up with another approach. This should work

```
render json: shop.to_json(:include => [locations: {include: [:categories]}])
```

Comment: I get this error: ```api/shops_controller.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => ...tions: { include: {:categories}}}) ... ^```   (I used your code exactly)

Comment: @Blankman Weird! It should work as per the docs. Anyways try this approach `shop.to_json(:include => [locations: {include: [:categories]}])`

Comment: It feels like I I spent the entire day on this thanks!!